# How do I handle CAPTCHA challenges from within a Windows application?

Tags: c#, html, .net, wpf, captcha

I am trying to programmatically fill out HTML forms from within a C#.NET WPF application. I have had great success with this until I came up against a CAPTCHA challenge required on one of the forms. Is there any way to load this CAPTCHA image inside the application for a user to see and respond to? Or can you think of a better way to handle this scenario? An example of such a form is available at: 
http://www.medwow.com/sale_offer_mgr.php?actions=sale_form&st=1

Comment: Holy god... to select that with jQuery you would need something like `$('div#page_template div form fieldset:last div table tbody tr td table tbody tr td.cell_title img').attr('src');` I'll try and get something working in XElements.

Comment: Not only that... but accessing it after that changes the image. It generates a new CAPTCHA for the same session ID upon refresh...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URI and loop through the HTML elements. Looking at the Captcha the element looks like this:

The images then will be: 87627...
[image: medwow Captcha]

So find the ID "Captcha_image" and then the src, load the source into an image box, similar to whats here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b7336f23-f011-4469-83f0-5e4e62ce97c1/

in 2 steps without code thats it!